# Architecture for email service API

Tags: architecture, api, asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-web-api

I would like to build an application for sending emails. So I chose ASP.NET Core (API) which will be deployed by Docker.
The application will get some request and "do some things" and then sends emails via Google SMTP.
There's a Template that already exists ... so the system replaces tabs in the template with real data and sends it.
For sending emails I would like to use third part library MailKit which support .NET Core.

It's probably going to need some kind of Token Authentication system as well, so I think about JWT. I would like to use SQL Server, so I chose Entity Framework Core.

It would be nice to have an UI that allows for some kind of reporting of what's been sent and maybe a way of CE (Customer Experience Team) uploading and testing new templates.
So I think the best way is to create another web application and I would like to use Angular or React.

To sum up:
API:
ASP.NET Core with JWT and EntityFramework Core

WEB:
Angular or React (or maybe Vue.js)

What do you think about it? Is it a good idea?

Comment: see [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the idea being good or bad doesn't really matter. The implementation of the idea is the point.

Second, your description is VERY HIGH level... in terms of software architecture, everything fits in there.

Third, if you're aiming BIG, i'd suggest a more scalable database infrastructure... have a look at Azure Table or DocumentDb...

Forth, if you're using .Net Core, i'd suggest that you look at App Services for Linux, which is basically a wrapper around docker that leverages other Azure App Services tools priorly available only to regular .Net code... and so far, 50% cheaper.